# chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow returns undefined value

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

```
function Login() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const authenticate = async () => {
            const clientId = 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com'; 
            const redirectUri = encodeURI('http://' + chrome.runtime.id + '.chromiumapp.org')
            const scopes = 'email profile';

            const authUrl = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=code&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scopes)}`;

            try {
                // Launch the authentication flow
                console.log(redirectUri);

                const redirectUrl = await new Promise((resolve) => {
                    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({ url: authUrl, interactive: true }, (responseUrl) =>                 
                    {                       
                        console.log(responseUrl) // returns undefined
                        resolve(responseUrl);
                    });
                })

                console.log(redirectUrl);
                const authCode = extractAuthCodeFromUrl(redirectUrl);
                console.log(authCode);

                // Send the auth code to your server for further processing
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/google/callback', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ code: authCode }),
                });
                console.log(response);
                 
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        };

        document.getElementById('loginButton').addEventListener('click', authenticate);

        return () => {
            document.getElementById('loginButton').removeEventListener('click', authenticate);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <button id="loginButton">
            Login
        </button>
    );
};

function extractAuthCodeFromUrl(redirectUrl) {
    const regex = /[?&]code=([^&#]*)/;
    const results = regex.exec(redirectUrl);
    return results ? decodeURIComponent(results[1]) : null;
}

export default Login;
```

I am trying to build an extension and wanted to implement Oauth login, after trying out multiple things such as passport, which did not work out, I found this web auth flow solution, but I am getting undefined values

[image]

I expect it to return the response token

Comment: It's undefined apparently because there's an error as shown in your screenshot.